# Java - edit manifest.mf to have .class and .java files in a JAR

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I would like to have .class and .java files in a JAR. Thus, I have "bin" and "src" pastes in that JAR. How should I edit the MANIFEST.MF?

```
JAR
 |
  -- bin -- .class files
 |
  -- src -- .java files
 |
  -- META-INF -- MANIFEST.FM
```

Im doing this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: ./bin/ 
Main-Class: simul.Simulador
```

But with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file structure should be something like this; the root of the package structure for the class files *must* be at the top level in the jar.

```
JAR
 |
  -- simul
 |    |
 |     -- Simulador.class
 |    |
 |     -- (other class files in "simul" package ...)
 |
  -- META-INF
      |
       -- src -- .java files
      |
       -- MANIFEST.MF
```

Your manifest should look like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: simul.Simulador
```

The Class-Path attribute should only be used to refer to other JARs (or exploded class directories) external to the current jar file. It's not a path inside the jar.